# Does Rubyist call Argument Lists and Array both Array?

Tags: ruby

I'm simply curious about how the terms are used, so I have a question.

First, let me quote where the terms are used.

quote from Active Record document:
[Active Record Query Interface — Ruby on Rails Guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#array-conditions)

> **2 Conditions**
> Conditions can either be specified as a string, array, or hash.
>
> **2.2 Array Conditions**
> Now what if that number could vary, say as an argument from somewhere? The find
> would then take the form:
> `Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])`

## I was confused

```
Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I was confused the document. Does the document refer to `^^^` part as Array?. I think ruby Array is `[  ]`.

I found other site call this **Argument Lists**.
[Programming Ruby: The Pragmatic Programmer's Guide](http://ruby-doc.com/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/tut_methods.html)

In Ruby It does what is called?

```
def f(a, b)
end

f(1, 2)
 ^^^^^^
```

Array or List?
Array and List?

How do you distinguish Array and List in Ruby?

Comment: method arguments,where is the receiver

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> `Client.where("orders_count = ?", params[:orders])` ... this is Array?

No, this is not an array. These are two arguments.

> How do you distinguish Array and List in Ruby?

*Argument list* refers to a method's arguments, it's not a class.
You can provide an argument list when defining a method:

```
def foo(a, b)
  p a: a, b: b
end
```

`foo` is the method name and `a, b` is the argument list.

When calling a method, the passed arguments may also be called *argument list*:

```
foo 1, 2 # prints {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

`1, 2` is the argument list.

#### Converting between array and argument list

You can convert an array into a argument list by using `*`:

```
foo *[1, 2] # prints {:a=>1, :b=>2}
```

You can also convert an argument list to an array by prefixing an argument with `*` in the method definition:

```
def bar(*args)
  p args
end
```

This allows the method to take a variable number of arguments:

```
bar 1, 2 # prints [1, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

In Ruby an argument list can be handled as both - an array or single arguments - depending on the assignment:

```
a, b, c = 1, 2, 3
a #=> 1
b #=> 2
c #=> 3
```

But:

```
array = 1, 2, 3
array #=> [1, 2, 3]
```